# BatchRequest effect on API quotas

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have 2 questions regarding how quotas are calculated/enforced for the Google Drive SDK for .NET.

1.**File insert & Permission insert**

If I have code like this: (pseudocode)

```
Insert file
Insert permission A on file
Insert permission B on file
Insert permission C on file
Insert permission D on file
```

For the purposes of quota enforcement, does the above count as 1 request or 5 requests?

Given that we've seen roughly a rate limit of usually 1 item/sec, does these mean that the above code will run in 5 seconds? Or do the permission setting operation not participate in the scope of the rate-limit?

2.**BatchRequest**

Does the new [Batch](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/Batch) capability of the .NET version of the Google APIs client library help me with regards to quotas?

```
Insert file
BatchRequest( InsertPermission(file, A),
              InsertPermission(file, B), 
              InsertPermission(file, C), 
              InsertPermission(file, D)
            )
```

For the purposes of quota enforcement, does the above count as 1 request, 2 requests, or 5 requests?

Answer (score 1):

For batch requests, each individual request (requests A, B, C and D in your case) is in the same pipeline as it was processed in non batch request.

So, quota check runs against each part of a batch request.
In the question above, both cases should result in the number of quota enforcement checks.